# Different Focus on Dual Monitors

Tags: focus, monitor, multiple-monitors

I have installed dual monitor on my system. I am running a process which continuously takes focus of browser. This way, I am unable to work on some other application as other application loses focus again and again.

Is there any way by which i can set different focus for different monitors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I say "no" because focus can be only one.
Otherwise what would happen when you click "Ctrl+C" or "Alt+F4" or every other key combination that assumes you have 1 focused application/element?

Your solution is to deal with that application stealing your focus.

Comment: you are right but is there any software or hack that can allow me to do so?

Comment: You should be more specific about your problem with that application that steals your focus. What is that application and why does it steals it?

Comment: that is a process which is running in browser and it needs browser focus always to run.

Comment: You should deal with that process. There should be no app constantly stealing focus just for running.

Comment: @KromStern Actually it can be legitimate in a few cases--online tests and the like.

Comment: @LorenPechtel: I would like to see such an example ;)

Comment: @KromStern I'm thinking of as an anti-cheating measure--in a school or the like, not something for an arbitrary audience.